# How to use Expanded and a Container with a fixed height together in a column without overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

Simply put, I want the following code to run without overflow.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('TestApp')),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Normally, there is no problem, but when the height of the screen is smaller than 100, overflow happens. Instead of overflowing, I want the height to be reduced.

I tried SingleChildScrollView and Wrap, and then Expanded was unavailable.And using ConstrainedBox to set MaxHeight to 100, still, there was an overflow.

Comment: Try with `Flexible`

Comment: If `Flexible` is used, when the screen height decreases below a certain height, both container's heights decrease together. I want the blue to run out first, then the red to run out.

Comment: What behavior do you want ? add a scroll or just resize your red container when the height is too small?

Comment: What I want is for the 'max-height' of the red container to appear to be 100. If the screen height is greater than 100, both the red and blue containers are visible, if less than 100, the blue container is not visible, and the height of the red container is the same as the screen height. I could make the height of the red container smaller, but once faced with this problem, I want to know the answer.

Comment: try `LayoutBuilder` then, more https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: Thank you. It does work. But is `LayoutBuilder` really the best option? It looks really inefficient and it's not well readable.

Comment: well, honestly I would use `CustomMultiChildLayout` but `LayoutBuilder` is better for newstarters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take aid of `MediaQuery` class,  if you want to avoid `LayoutBuilder`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final minHeight = 100;

  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: screenHeight < minHeight  ? screenHeight : 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: screenHeight < minHeight  ? 0 : 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```